# Where I can find the UML class diagram's official metamodel?

Tags: class, uml, abstract, diagram, metamodel

I've searched for the UML class diagram metamodel on the UML/OMG web site, but I found nothing. I'm not looking for a somebody's interpretation, I really wanted the oficial metamodel specification.

I will be glad if anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it's there since I downloaded it not too long ago. But it's hidden well. Trying to find it back...

Comment: Ah! Geert placed it here: http://community.sparxsystems.com/community-resources/492-64ea-uml-meta-model

Comment: http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/ 2nd from below

Comment: Do you really mean the metamodel for the diagrams? That would be diagram definition and diagram interchange specs.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you are conflating the terms *model* and *diagram*.

A diagram is just a visualization of a model or its part, it is **not** the model itself.

So what you can have is a single UML model representing your entire system and then you use different diagrams to see only parts of the model… in class diagrams you are focusing primarily on the structure of the model, in state machine diagrams you are looking at some particular behavior, etc.

But the metamodel describing the model is still the same, as described in [the specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/).

Some more tips/references that may help you:

- Read Annex A
- Class diagrams are focused on structural representation, so chapter 11. Structured Classifiers may get you started
- A chapter (such as 9.6. Operations) typically contains "Notation" and "Examples" sections that explain how the element is to be visualized in a diagram
- Diagram Interchange (Annex B of UML Specs linked above) and [Diagram Definition](http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/1.1) describe the meta-model behind diagrams, however this may be yet something else then what you are looking for

Comment: Great answer! You beat me to it!

Answer (score 2):

- [UML Spec Overview](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)
- [UML 2.5 Spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/)
- [UML 2.1 Spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1.2/)

Comment: I've already saw those docs, but I couldn't find the class diagram's abstract sintax (the metamodel)...

Comment: There is no meta-model for diagrams. Only for Elements that are often used on diagrams such as Class, Property, Operation, Association. Diagrams aren't really part of the UML meta-model.